# Decrease/increase for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like so:

```
...
const STARTING_OPACITY = 0.3;
const STARTING_HEIGHT = ageVariable === 5 ? 70 : 20;
const opacityInterval = (1 - STARTING_OPACITY) / yearlyContr;
const heightInterval = (100 - STARTING_HEIGHT) / yearlyContr;
...

...
return (
    columns.map(
        (column, i) => {
            return(
                <Column height={STARTING_HEIGHT + (heightInterval * getBarsHeight(columns))}  key={`id-${i}`}>
                    <MonthlyContribution>£{column}</MonthlyContribution>
                    <ProgressionBar  
                        opacity={((STARTING_OPACITY + (opacityInterval * i)))}
                    />
                    <AgeContainer>{age + (i * ageVariable)}</AgeContainer>
                </Column>
            );
        }
    )
);
...
```

and the key function is:

```
const isDecreasing = (firstPayment, secondPayment) => firstPayment > secondPayment;

let heightVariable;

const getBarsHeight = arr => {
    const getIsDecreasing = isDecreasing(arr[0], arr[1]);
    const arrLength = arr.length;

    if (getIsDecreasing) {
        for (let i = arrLength; i >= 0; i--) {
            heightVariable = i;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
            heightVariable = i;
        }
    }

    return heightVariable;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that if I have an array like so:

```
[1,2,3]
```

the height prop on the column component will increase gradually or viceversa if the array is like so:

```
[3,2,1]
```

at the moment I am always getting the same height prop value.

Comment: You are passing the variable `columns` to `getBarsHeight` every time, so of course it always returns the same value because `columns` doesn't change between the different loops.

Comment: Also, you are essentially just returning the last value of `i` so your height will always be either the array's length-1 or 0 depending on whether it is incresing or not. So the loop is not nescesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBarsHeight` needs to be aware of the index to provide different value for different indexes => `getBarsHeight(columns, i)`:

```
const getBarsHeight = (arr, i) => {
  const isDecreasing = arr[0] > arr[1]
  return isDecreasing ? arr.length - i : i + 1
}
```